# trying to config git bash to python see attachment for error

Tags: error-handling, config, alias

I was trying to config git bash to python and got an error see attachment for error. I have tried everything

everything suggested in stack overflow nothing works..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8lSE.png)

Comment: Please post the error as text, not just image

Comment: bash: export: `PATH:/c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3/Scripts
export PATH=PATH:c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3:c/Users.tweet/Anaconda3/Scripts:c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3:c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/Anaconda3/Scripts': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `python.exe
export PATH=PATH:c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3:c/Users.tweet/Anaconda3/Scripts:c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3:c/Users/tweet/Anaconda3/Scripts: c/Users/tweet/anaconda3:c/Users/tweet/anaconda3/Scripts': not a valid identifier
bash: alias: `python.exe
export PATH': invalid alias name
bash: alais: command not found

Comment: it just keeps repeating when  i open git